# Optional url parameters in AngularJs Resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this kind of resource: `var Products = $resource('companies/:companyId/products')`
The problem is, that I would like to get the products of all companies by url `companies/products`, but using resource and not providing companyId I am getting `companies//products`. Probably I could use another url, like just `/products`, but does it mean that I have to have another resource for the same thing?

In this simple case I could change the url to `companies/products/:companyId`, but it seems to be  quite general case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, currently you need to define another $resource.

But you can wrap multiple instances of $resource into a single service if you want...

```
app.factory('mergedRes', function($resource) {
  var r1 = $resource('/companies/:companyId/products');
      r2 = $resource('/companies/products');

  r1.getAll = r2.query.bind(r2);

  return r1;
});
```

Comment: what if you want to chain 3 difference resources, how would that look like?

Comment: I have tried this solution but it is still showing r1's `/companies//products` even if `companyId` is empty.