# AngularJS resource optional path parameters

Tags: angularjs, rest, path-parameter

I'm using an *AngularJS $resource factory* to access a client REST services. Some of the parameters are defined with optional path parameters rather than query parameters.

**Case 1:**

I call *myUrl/application-:applicationID/limit-:limit.json*

with:

```
{
    applicationID:"1234",
    limit: 10
}
```

I get the correct URL of *myUrl/application-1234/limit-10.json*

**Case 2:**

I call *myUrl/application-:applicationID/limit-:limit.json*

with:

```
{
    applicationID:"1234"
}
```

I want the resulting url to ignore the optional `limit` parameter and collapse down to *myUrl/application-1234.json*

However, what I get is *myUrl/application-1234/limit-.json*

*EDIT
I have several API categories eg Foo1, Foo2, and each has several endpoints eg endPoint1, endPoint2 and using the method in @Deiter's post, I can't see a way to cleanly list all my resources without using temporary category names then binding them all together at the end.

```
MyServices.factory ( 'MyAPI', ['$resource',

function ( $resource ) {

    return {

    Foo1: $resource ( '', 
    {                       
        application: "@applicationID",
        limit: "@limit"
    }, 
    {           
        endPoint1: {
            ...
        },
        endPoint2: { 
            url: "myURL/application-:applicationID/limit-:limit.json",
            method:'GET', 
            isArray:true
        },
    }),     

    Foo2: $resource ( '', 
    {                       
        application: "@applicationID"
    }, 
    {           
        endPoint1: { 
            ...
        },
        endPoint2: { 
            ...
        }
    }),             
}               
}]);
```

Example call:

```
MyAPI.Foo1.endPoint1 ( { application: "1", limit: 5 } ); 
MyAPI.Foo2.endPoint2 ( { application: "1" } );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [optional-url-parameters-in-angularjs-resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382337/optional-url-parameters-in-angularjs-resource)

Comment: I've edited my original post to show my current structure as I'm not sure how to cleanly integrate the method in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the related answer given in the comments by @Dieter, and create separate $resources, but I would suggest simply making each piece of the URL consistent. Do this by  either:

1) Removing the static component of each variable part (eg. `myUrl/1234/10`)

2) Passing the actual value to the URL that you want to use, and keeping the entire part variable (eg. `myUrl/:applicationID/:limit`, and pass in `application-1234` & `limit-10`)

Comment: I've edited my original post to show the current structure.  If I understand you correctly, you suggest that I pass in the key and value pair in the string parameter rather than just the value?

Comment: Yeah. But I also feel like the `application-` and `limit-` are quite redundant.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree with you about the url structure but there are quite a lot of endpoints and it's already been deployed on a large multi-platform site, so unfortunately it's very unlikely they will change it.